# find max value without aggregate operator in mysql

Tags: mysql

how to find the maximum value in a column with integer values without using aggregate operator in mysql

Comment: and you don't want an aggregate operator because?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT <Value>
FROM <YourTable>
ORDER BY <Value> DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
SELECT IntColumn FROM MyTable ORDER BY IntColumn DESC LIMIT 1
```