# How to get the max value of a field without grouping in MySql

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I have a query with many wheres and orders criterias. One of the fields of the select is 'price' (element price) but I would like to have also (in every row) the maximun price of all the selected elements.

I tried to include MAX aggregate function on select hoping that this will return desired value, but insetead of that, price and MAX(price) returns the same. Searching into MySql doc I found the reason:

> If you use a group function in a
>   statement containing no GROUP BY
>   clause, it is equivalent to grouping
>   on all rows.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

There's a similar question (but not resolving this): [find max value without aggregate operator in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714687/find-max-value-without-aggregate-operator-in-mysql)

Comment: looks like sub-query can fix, but without table schema, that's nothing much can guess, please update the Question will full table schema

Comment: Do you want the max(price) in the table or max(price) within the selected data set?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    price,
    (SELECT MAX(price) FROM your_table) AS max_price
FROM your_table
```

I'm not sure why you'd want to return that value on every row though... I'd probably do this in two separate queries, or else use a UNION ALL:

```
SELECT id, price FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, MAX(price) FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a stored procedure like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE QueryWithMax ([parameter list if necessary])
BEGIN

    -- Obtain the maximum price
    DECLARE x INT UNSIGNED; -- change datatype if appropriate
    SET x = SELECT
                MAX(price)
            FROM
                ...
            WHERE
                ...
            ;

    -- Now do your query
    SELECT
        price,
        [other columns],
        x AS MaxPrice
    FROM
        ...
    WHERE
        ...
    GROUP BY
        ...
    ;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but if you had a subquery that extracts the maximum price (so you get one row), and then do a cross join (cartesian product) with it. You should get something like what you want. I can't vouch for how fast this would be.